# Flutter: Can I use Provider.of<Class> in normal class components?

Tags: flutter, class, dart, refactoring, flutter-provider

to propagate properties or methods down the tree in Flutter widgets, I usually use the Provider package with `Provider.of<someClass>(context).doSomething()`. Now, I also have normal class based components that do something, e.g File handling or so.
Can I somehow inject or use my Provider class in normal class components, too?
I assume its not possible the usual way, because Provider needs a context, but is there another way?

Comment: provider is for flutter but state managements like bloc can use with pure dart for managing states

Comment: hmm ok, but looks like a bit of an overkill for my purpose, I think I would plain simple just use a class member to save an instance of my other class inside my Provider class... this way I can still access all the class members' class methods and properties from inside my filehandler class...

Comment: you can use singleton pattern

Comment: @HadiNorouzi yeah, but I think when I use Provider<FileHandler> and initialize it once in main in the Providers array, it gets created only once anyway... and in the Provider<FileHandler> class I instantiate my other class as static (or not static) class variable only once, therefore it should be a singleton for this app anyways... no need for special constructs there then I think